# Creating buttons (all controls Behaviour) in XNA

Tags: c#, xna

I am just a hobby programmer.. and even tough I know how, I don't want to mix windows forms and XNA for my level editor.

Has anyone done this before? Are there any examples around how to create "Windows like" controls for XNA, including events like mouse over, click and double-click and even accept keyboard input(if possible using language specific keyboard input)?

Below you find the basic layout of my editor but it needs so much more.

[image: Basic thing I need]

Answer (score 0):

Yeah.

I'm now creating something like that.
See [my project](https://bitbucket.org/prostokiriuha/windrock/src) on Bitbucket.

I'm making own lib and voxel engine for Minecraft-like game. Just for fun.
So, in GameHelper lib you can fing folders Input (keyboard and mouse input) and GUI (forms and controls with events). I will be happy if it helps you, but there is almost no comment :P
Examples of use you can find in the Player class in main project (see ProcessInput method).

If you need I can give you better examples :)

Comment: I'll take a look... don't worry about comments c# reads like English for me :)